# PYTHON: generar numeros aleatorios en un rango.. Ejemplo : 0 - 100

Tags: python

**Buenas!!**

Quisiera saber si con phyton se podrian generar un numero aleatorio en un rango, por ejemplo que el rango sea 0-100..

Es para una tarea de un curso que estoy haciendo, si me pudieran ayudar se los agradeceria..

Answer (score 3):

Buen dia.

Mira el siguiente link, en el segundo subtitulo podras encontrar la forma de generar un numero aleatorio segun dos parametros que le pases, los cuales serian el rango que tu deseas, adicional, te explica la funcionalidad de demas metodos en torno a random:

http://www.mclibre.org/consultar/python/lecciones/python-biblioteca-random.html

```
from random import randint

print(randint(1, 50)) //Donde 1 y 50 son los rangos.
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias !

Comment: Con gusto, recuerda poner la pregunta como resuelta, para que si otra persona tiene la misma duda pueda observar que fue resuelta de forma correcta según la necesidad del autor de la pregunta.